# How to handle the same request twice in ASP.Net Pipeline and return the result to the client

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, asp.net-4.5

The user/browser sends a POST message to my Web Service, in some rare case this message causes an exception, I catch the exception and I would like to transfer the exact same message through the ASP.Net pipeline **again** and return the result to the original call.

I've tried using Server.Transfer and Server.TransferRequest but all I got was "Error executing child request".
Redirecting the user would also be problematic because I need to keep the message as POST, not GET.

Is that possible to do? How?

Thank you.

Comment: How is this related to WIF? Also, can you specify what is your Web Service based on: ASP.NET Web API, ASP.NET MVC, WCF, ... something else?

Comment: You're right, I'll remove this header.
ASP.Net with WCF Services. No MVC or WebApi.

Comment: For MVC applications, you can write custom IHttpModule that would use ControllerFactory to build controller again and invoke Execute method on it - forcing pipeline to restart again. For Web Forms, I'm not sure sure on how to do that unfortunately.